# Azure DevOps Server Repos

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, repo, azure-repos

Is there a way to restrict users from pushing new branches?

Our management wants the Repo admin to control what branches get created, they don't want devs pushing branches to a repo from their desktops in order to create them.

Is there a way to lock branch creation/pushes?  I know you can lock an EXISTING branch, but how about a net new branch a dev pushes to ADS?

Comment: Have you tried to enforce permissions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/require-branch-folders?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#enforce-permissions

Comment: Most hosting sites do have this as a feature, but each one does it differently, so the generic tag [tag:git] does not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to lock branch creation/pushes?

To limit users to create new branches, you can set the permission of the users/group.

You can navigate to **Project Settings -> Repositories-> Select Repository -> Security** and set the permission: **Create branch** as **Deny**.

For example:

[image]

Then the users will have no access to create/push branch via UI or Git commnad.